# Can Python statsmodels saved model file be converted to ONNX Runtime format?

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, arima, onnxruntime

I was trying to a SARIMA model from python statsmodels as a pickle file. I wanted to convert the saved time series model into ONNX runtime format for real time edge inference. But I did not find any ways to do so? Is it possible to convert the saved model from pickle to ONNX runtime format?

Comment: There is no support to exporting any of the statsmodels models to other packages.

Comment: Is there any other workaround to do this? Like saving the statsmodel into pickle files or json dumps and then converting that to ONNX formats?

Comment: While you can pickle statsmodels models, I don't have any knowledge of how you might incorporate these into ONNX.